# How to cache result for a function with variable arguments (Varargs) in Java

Tags: java, caching

I have Java method like this:

```
  public <T> T queryDB(Class<T> klass, Object... objects) {
    return dbClient.get(klass, objects);
  }
```

How can I cache this call? It is using variable arguments. I am not sure how to correctly build a cache key?

Comment: Is it a option to replace the generic type T with an interface which defines an unique key?

Answer (score 1):

If you return some value based on your `klass` and `object` variables that means you have a composite key of `klass` and `object`.

What you can can do is to encapsulate these objects into a class, say, `MyKey`:

```
      public class MyKey <T> {
             Class<T> klass;
             Object[] objects;

             public MyKey(Class<T> klass, Object... objects) {
                    this.klass = klass;
                    this.objects = objects;
             }

             @Override
             public boolean equals(Object obj) {
                    //implement this method comparing klass and objects
             }

             @Override
             public int hashCode() {
                    //calculate a hash based on klass and objects' hashes
             }
       }
```

Override `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods of this class (mandatory!) that calculate their values based on `klass` and objects `variables`.
**Note**: `objects` is an array, so you have to use `Arrays.equals()` method to compare it.

And finally, create a `HashMap` with your `MyKey` class as a key and the cached value as the map's value:

```
Map<MyKey<T>, T> cache = new HashMap<>();
```

Each time you want to check if the value is hashed, call

```
cache.get(new MyKey(klass, objects));
```

Comment: Does lombok's @EqualsAndHashCode help here?

Comment: Yes, it can help here, as far as I know